# calling C# function from aspx code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a C# function from aspx code when I type in something in the text box. How can I call a C# function from aspx code on a key down event of a text box.?

Comment: make ajax call on key down event and call c# function what you want

Comment: @alwaysrelax : Can you provide me with an example to code, because I have never used it and I am not aware of the syntax

Answer (score 2):

Make a Key Down Event

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Function1();
}
```

Function

```
private void Function1()
{
}
```

Comment: I am using web application not windows application. I Get ontextchaged  vent in web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery ajax -

```
var ListPostalCode = ["12345"];
 var PostalCodeJsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: ListPostalCode });
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "JobManagement.aspx/FindLocation",
              data: PostalCodeJsonText,
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) {              
                alert(response.d);
              },
              failure: function (response) {
                  alert(response.d);                
              }
            });
```

C# WebMethod -

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string FindLocation(List<string> list)
        {            
            try{
            string LocationInfo = "";
            HttpWebRequest FindLocationreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ziptasticapi.com/" + list[0]);
            FindLocationreq.Method = "GET";
            using (WebResponse Statusresponse = FindLocationreq.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Statusresponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    LocationInfo = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return LocationInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

[Reference 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1743208.aspx/1)

[Reference 2](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1127-consuming-web-service-webmethod-from-jquery-in-aspnet.aspx)

[Reference 3](http://deebujacob.blogspot.in/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

JS:

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {//if enter key is pressed condition
            __doPostBack('<%=Button1.UniqueId%>', "");
        }
    }
```

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: If i am searching some records in the grid and when I type USA in the text box , How will I handle .? Do I have to check the ascii key everytime. I will give you a link for you to see what exactly I am trying to replicate. 

http://theme.eakroko.de/flat this is the link and after going to the link got to large tables from the top menu and go to  Dynamic ajax loading (2500 entries)
grid and search some key word.

Comment: ohh this is autocomplete...for that you need to use webservice

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#target").keypress(function() {
    var value=$("#target").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Webservices/yourwebservice.asmx/webmethodName",
    data: "{value: " + value + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
   );
   });
```

you can make the call to your webmethod like this on key press.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('#MyTextBox').keyup(function() {
       var jsonObj = { c: $(this).val() };
       $.ajax({ 
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'webservice.aspx/MyCSharpFunction',
           data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
           }
       });
   });

});
```

C# (webservice.aspx in this example):

```
public partial class webservice : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string MyCSharpFunction(string c)
    {
        return "You typed " + c;
    }

}
```

Comment: How will I populate the grid which is in different form using above method.?